# LLVM C API building global str pointer fails with segmentation error before building any functions

Tags: c, llvm

I am writing a front-end with Java 11 using [LLVM C API](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/llvm) and I have a really strange issue when creating global strings.

So when I create local string, I use the following method and get its reference:

```
LLVMValueRef valueRef = LLVMBuildGlobalStringPtr(builder, stringValue, constantName);
```

And it beatutifully generates the following code:

```
@someText.glob = private unnamed_addr constant [4 x i8] c"asd\00", align 1

define i8* @test() {
entry:
  ret i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @someText.glob, i64 0, i64 0)
}
```

In this case `LLVMBuildGlobalStringPtr` is called after constructing `test` method:

```
...creating fun args...
LLVMValueRef funRef = LLVMAddFunction(mod, "test", LLVMFunctionType(funReturnType, paramTypes, numberOfParams, FALSE));
LLVMSetFunctionCallConv(funRef, LLVMCCallConv);
...creating entry and end blocks...
"CALLING LLVMBuildGlobalStringPtr HERE"
LLVMBuildRet(builder, returnValueRef);
```

However when a global variable is created **BEFORE** constructing `test` function (or any other functions) with `LLVMBuildGlobalStringPtr`, it immediately fails with segmentation fault:

```
...
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000131bf8c2c, pid=1858, tid=10243
...
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libLLVM.dylib+0x240c2c]  llvm::IRBuilderBase::CreateGlobalString(llvm::StringRef, llvm::Twine const&, unsigned int)+0x2c
...
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

As a second option I also tried returning plain string with:

```
LLVMConstString(stringValue, stringValue.length(), FALSE);
```

And then creating global variables manually:

```
LLVMTypeRef llvmTypeRef = LLVMTypeOf(assignedValueRef);
LLVMValueRef globalVar = LLVMAddGlobal(mod, llvmTypeRef, identifier);
LLVMSetInitializer(globalVar, assignedValueRef);
```

However in this case I get type mismatch error:

```
Function return type does not match operand type of return inst!
  ret [4 x i8]* @someText
 i8*LLVM ERROR: Broken module found, compilation aborted!
```

It's because my variable is `i8*` but the `LLVMConstString` returns type of `[4 x i8]`. So therefore I tried bitcasting to `i8*`.

```
LLVMConstBitCast(LLVMConstString(stringValue, stringValue.length(), FALSE), LLVMPointerType(LLVMInt8Type(), 0))
```

But it failed again with:

```
Invalid bitcast
i8* bitcast ([4 x i8] c"asd\00" to i8*)
```

So I went back to `LLVMBuildGlobalStringPtr` and solved this by creating `main` function always **BEFORE** creating any global variables. But it completely feels a hacky solution and yet I'm probably missing some string based concept regarding LLVM or something is unitialized at that point.

Comment: Try running your frontend with valgrind, it usually tells you what's uninitialised in the time it takes to write a comment like this one.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! For now I'll move on with the LLVM C++ API with JNI manually, but I will go back for this and check the memory issue. If it's something bad I'll create a ticket for the GitHub owners.

Comment: I think you will find that Valgrind finds no issues in LLVM itself, but rather points out uninitialised variables in *your* code.

Comment: Any update on this problem?

Comment: @CWKSC No, I didn't have time to investigate the issue, so it was faster to extract that part of my Java program into a C++ program with CMake, and using the C++ LLVM API. You can get the API easily by vcpkg or conan and use it via CMake:  https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#embedding-llvm-in-your-project

Plus there is a very good example program on their site:
https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/index.html